# EditText on Dialog returns no text

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext

I am so tired on finding  the mistake. I didn't find any mistake but I am getting no text from editText. please Look at following Code:

**activity_pwd.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter PIN "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pwdValue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

I called **LockImmediately(this);** on **onCreate** method of **MainActivity**

```
    public void LockImmediately(Context context) {
    if (lock_app) {
        View myview = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_pwd,null);
        enterPWD  = (EditText) myview.findViewById(R.id.pwdValue);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setCancelable(false)
                .setView(R.layout.activity_pwd).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String user_text = enterPWD.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("onCreate pws", " i "+user_text);
                        if (pwd.equals(user_text)) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Log.d("onCreate", "Work done");
                        } else {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    }
                }).create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

**Log.d**

```
 02-15 23:15:30.840 29379-29379/com.developersqueen.wishlater D/onCreate: onCreate
 02-15 23:15:37.021 29379-29379/com.developersqueen.wishlater D/onCreate pws:  i 
 02-15 23:15:45.427 29379-29379/com.developersqueen.wishlater D/onCreate:  onCreate
 02-15 23:15:49.026 29379-29379/com.developersqueen.wishlater D/onCreate pws:  i
```

You can see that log above that I have concatenate edittext value with "i" but it's returning no value.. I have tried clearing data, unistalling app, clean, build everything but  same result always!! Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: try changing `enterPWD.getText().toString();` to `alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.pwdValue).getText().toString();`, and see if it works

Comment: no it's  giving error on compiling illegal character \u200c

Comment: Then remove that illegal character and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting the view to the AlertDialog, you should set the view, where you found the ID of the EditText.

You have used **myview** to find the ID of the EditText, but you are trying to get myView from the Activity, not from the Dialog.

If you set the view to be **myview**, you can get the text from the **enterPWD** EditText.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setCancelable(false)
                .setView(myview).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
...
}
```

You should create a separate layout for the Activity and for the Dialog itself. Not to use one layout for both.

Answer (score 0):

You inflate a `View` and drop it,

`View myview = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_pwd,null);` is NOT the `View` of the Dialog, its a useless instance.

You pass the id of the layout to the dialog, which inflates it's own version of it in `.show()`.
Use `alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.pwdValue)` directly in `onClick(..)` instead.

Comment: let me check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public void LockImmediately(Context context) {
    if (lock_app) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new   AlertDialog.Builder(this).setCancelable(false)
                .setView(R.layout.activity_pwd).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            EditText enterPWD  = (EditText) myview.findViewById(R.id.pwdValue);
                            String user_text = enterPWD.getText().toString();
                            Log.d("onCreate pws", " i "+user_text);
                            if (pwd.equals(user_text)) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                Log.d("onCreate", "Work done");
                            } else {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                MainActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        }
                    }).create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what changes do you made sir?

Comment: I remove your layout inflating and initial edit text inside the on click @appleappala